# extracting a substring from a text column in hive

Tags: hive, hql

We have text data in a column named title like below

```
"id":"S-1-98-13474422323-33566802","name":"uid=Xzdpr0,ou=people,dc=vm,dc=com","shortName":"XZDPR0","displayName":"Jund Lee","emailAddress":"jund.lee@bm.com","title":"Leading Product Investor"
```

Need to extract just the display  name (Jund lee  in this example) from the above  text data in hive, I have tried using substring function but don't seem to work,Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **regexp_extract** function with the `matching` regex to capture only the `displayName` from your `title` field value.

**Ex:**

```
hive> with tb as(select string('"id":"S-1-98-13474422323-33566802",
         "name":"uid=Xzdpr0,ou=people,dc=vm,dc=com","shortName":"XZDPR0",
         "displayName":"Jund Lee","emailAddress":"jund.lee@bm.com",
         "title":"Leading Product Investor"')title) 
     select regexp_extract(title,'"displayName":"(.*?)"',1) title from tb;

+-----------+--+
|   title   |
+-----------+--+
| Jund Lee  |
+-----------+--+
```